# What is the different between Ever and Never?

Tags: meaning, grammar

Something I know using word *never*. For an example:

> I never do this thing.

but I don't know what is the meaning of *ever*. Can you describe me both *never* and *ever*?

Comment: Have you looked the word "ever" up in a dictionary? What did it say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Never X* is equivalent to *not ever X* with some shifting around of words.

> I never was there = I was not ever there.
>
> I never do this thing = I do not ever do this thing.

It's archaic to use *ever* without some negating word, so *ever X* is not really a commonly used "opposite" of *never X*.

> Nothing was ever in the box (fine because of *nothing*)
>
> Something was ever in the box (doesn't work)
>
> No one ever answered the door (fine because of *no one*)
>
> John ever answered the door (nope)

Using a negative word and *never* is a double negative and frowned upon, but you will hear it in live speech occasionally, often for emphasis.

> No one never came by!

Comment: In questions we can use either word, but we prefer 'ever.' For example we could say "Do you ever oversleep?" (without negation); and for some sort of emphasis we could say "Do you never oversleep?"

Comment: Also, depending on how it is used, 'ever' can mean either 'at any time' or 'at all times'.  For example, "We must remain ever vigilant" would mean "We must be vigilant at all times", whereas "Have you ever been late to work?" would ask "Have you been late to work at any time?"